# Shall be cause for vs Shall be the cause for

Tags: articles, legalese

When reviewing a rental agreement, I saw the following sentence:

> Violation of any part of this agreement shall be cause for eviction under applicable code sections.

Do we need a “the” in front of “cause”?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The sentence you are looking at contains a ["legalese"](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/legalese) use of the word *cause*.  In this context, *cause* is used to mean "a valid reason for something to happen", and it never takes an article.  You can usually tell that you're looking at this kind of usage of *cause* because of the phrase "cause for": we would say

> A snakebite was *the cause* of his paralysis. (that is, his paralysis happened because of a snakebite)

but

> We have much *cause* for celebration.  (that is, we have good reasons for celebrating)

or

> He was fired [for *cause*](https://www.lawwv.com/blog/2021/june/what-does-it-mean-to-be-fired-for-cause-/).  (that is, the company had a valid reason to fire him)

Reference: https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/cause